# User provided email over the landing page is not showing in the database in Django

Tags: python, django, backend

I am trying to put a subscribe email form on my landing page, however, I am not able to see the input email addresses on my admin(backend). Why it's not writing user-provided email input to my database?

base.html

```
   <form  method="post" > {% csrf_token %}
      <label >Your Email: </label>
      <input
      type="text">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.
class EmailSubmit(models.Model):
    email_name=models.EmailField(max_length=30)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import EmailSubmit

class EmailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=EmailSubmit
        fields=[
        'email_name',
        ]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import EmailForm



def index(request):
    return render(request, 'base.html')

def email_post(request):
    form = EmialForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    context={
        'form':form
    }
    return render(request, 'base.html', {'form': form})
```

so when the user puts the email and submit, the page refreshes but nothing shows up on the backend. What is wrong with my code here?

Comment: Are you sure for is valid? Can you show your template file?

Comment: @Charnel is something wrong with the form? Template file has a lot of stuff but this is what my forms look like in base.html.

Comment: What's the reason of using `<input type="text">` instead of `{{ form }}`?

Comment: I did that as well, still not loading the backend.

Comment: Simpy debug POST request and check what's inside request data. If it's ok - move to form valid method. If it return false - check form errors.

Answer (score 0):

Input field should have a name parameter

```
<input name="email_name">
```

or

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.email_name.errors }}
  {{ form.email_name.label_tag }}
  {{ form.email_name }}
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```